# How to get a managed metadata column value from first list item in a script editor webpart?

Tags: javascript, splistitem, sharepoint-rest-api, script

I have some list "SiteInformation". In this list there is always 1 list item. In this list item there is a managed metadata column.

I would like to create some script editor webpart. Inside this webpart I would like to show the managed metadata values (multiple). How to do this?

For now I have this logic to get the title. The next step is to get managed metadata values from 1 column "Countries":

```
getSiteTitle = function(requestUrl, success, fail){
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                fail(data);
            }
        });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('SiteInformation')?$top=1&$select=Title&$orderby=ID";
    getSiteTitle(url, function(data) {
        var title = "";
        var results = data.d.results;
        if(results != null && results.length > 0) {
            title = results[0].Title;
        }
        //logic to update title in your container
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Failed to load title");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your managed metadata column is going to be multi-valued, your results, will be in the form of any array.

Assuming that, the internal column name is `Countries`, you can use the below code:

```
getSiteTitle = function(requestUrl, success, fail){
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                fail(data);
            }
        });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('SiteInformation')?$top=1&$select=Title,Countries&$orderby=ID";
    getSiteTitle(url, function(data) {
        var title = "";
        var countries = "";
        var results = data.d.results;
        var countriesArray;
        if(results != null && results.length > 0) {
            title = results[0].Title;
            //it will be an array
            countriesArray = results[0].Countries.results;
            countriesArray.forEach(function(country) {
                //semi-colon separated country names
                countries+= country.Label + ';';
            });

        }
        //logic to update title in your container
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Failed to load title");
    }
});
```

Comment: hi @ola, did you try this ? is it working for you ?